# CAS Custom Principle Attributes Not Serialized To JSON

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, cas

So I have implemented my custom auth handler. I want to return some attributes after auth is done. But my attributes are not being serialized to proper JSON. Here is the sample:

```
@Override
protected AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(
    UsernamePasswordCredential credential, String originalPassword )
    throws GeneralSecurityException
{
// ----
final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, Object> parentRoles = new HashMap<>();
final Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();
roles.add("ADMIN");
parentRoles.put("TEST_1", roles);
attributes.put("roles", parentRoles);

return createHandlerResult( credential,
            this.getPrincipalFactory( ).createPrincipal( credential.getId( ), attributes) );
}
```

Expected JSON from the client side who calls the /v1/tickets URL:

```
{
// 
"roles":[{"TEST_1":["ADMIN"]}]
// 
}
```

Received:

```
{
roles=[(TEST_1,[ADMIN])]
}
```

It looks like my principal attributes not being serialized by the jackson, its toString is returned me directly. What could be the reason?

cas.version = 5.3.8

Comment: can you show this class `AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult`

Comment: @Deadpool I didn't implement it, Default one is being used (DefaultAuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult). So in the debug mode it returns SimplePrinciple with the attributes I inject